# How does chisel connect to such a port?

Tags: scala, riscv, chisel

I am learning the design of Boomv3.

The A part has a write port. The format is

```
val write_ports = Flipped(Vec(10, Valid(new RegisterFileWritePort(maxPregSz, registerWidth))))
```

B has a write port. The format is

```
val write_ports = Vec(5, Valid(new RegisterFileWritePort(maxPregSz, 4)))
```

C has a write port. The format is

```
val write_ports = Vec(5, Valid(new RegisterFileWritePort(maxPregSz, 4)))
```

I want to connect B and C to A.

When i use

```
A.write_ports  <> B.write_ports
A.write_ports  <> C.write_ports
```

, here will be a `failed @: Left and Right are different length Vecs`  error.

But my original intention is that the length of A is 10. The length of B and C are both 5. This makes them connect.

But what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With these two bulk connexions, Chisel can't find where to assign B and C 5-sized Vec to B 10-sized Vec.

You should concatenate B and C vec and write one bulk connexion :

```
A.write_ports  <> B.write_ports ++ C.write_ports
```

I tested it with [scatie here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/WSwRTstHT9mAidKxZMEaIQ).